# Teradata partition by col order by 0

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, teradata

While researching a previous problem of mine, I used the answer to [this post](http://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Sample-without-duplicates/m-p/5503/highlight/true#M2280). My query looks like this:

```
sel
  *
from (
    sel distinct
      COL,
      FIELD
    from TBL

    where COL in (
        -- subquery
    )
      and FIELD is not NULL
) q
qualify row_number() over (partition by COL order by 0) between 1 and 750
;
```

It does what I want it to do, but I don't fully understand it. The issue is in the `partition by COL order by 0` bit. I understand that `partition by` breaks the data into subgroups based on the values in the designated field and I understand that `order by`, when followed by a field name will sort the results of each partition by that field, but I don't understand how it operates with an integer. My assumption is that putting any constant in that spot will yield the same results. Is this assumption correct? Does `0` have some special meaning here?

Comment: Its just a dummy value given there to sort records in natural order in which it gets retrieved and assign row number value accordingly.

Comment: Do you not understand the result of ordering by a constant, or what's actually happening in the implementation, ex. how the ties are broken?

Comment: I don't understand the result of ordering by a constant and I'm not sure to which ties you are referring.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, OP. You could stick any value in there and you would get the same results. The ORDER BY clause of the OVER() portion of the window function is required when using ROW_NUMBER(). Sticking a constant in there is akin to saying "I don't care which records for COL you keep, just keep 750 of them"

Comment: Awesome. Do you mind posting that again as the answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Btw, running the same query a 2nd time might return different rows. But when you try to sample data, this approach will not result in a valid sample...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct. You could stick any value in there and you would get the same results.

The ORDER BY clause of the OVER() portion of the window function is required when using ROW_NUMBER().

Sticking a constant in there is akin to saying "I don't care which records for COL you keep, just keep 750 of them"

As @dnoeth pointed out, because you are ordering by a constant and because of the parallel nature of Teradata and how that affects data retrieval across the parallel systems (and the nature of RDBMS in general) there is no guarantee that you will get the same result between two runs.